# wordpress custom template read data from page casting

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a custom template that goes like...

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ranking
*/
```

And shows some html tables calculating rankings from users.

For the client to be able to select which tables to show it would be great if the page that casts the template, which is totally empty in general, could contain some form of meta-data that the template could read and show the tables based on it, so the client could create some pages of his own that looked like...

```html
<h1>Premier league Ranking</h1>

<meta-data>Division=1</meta-data>
```

Given that the PHP should execute before HTML is sent I don't know if this is remotely possible, but then, is there a good workaround?

Comment: Please fix your question, or it will be closed and/pr downvoated. Not only the formatting, describe it better as at the moment I have no idea what are you asking about.

Comment: Lol you didn't even give me 30 seconds :)

Comment: Why do you publish unfinished question? ;) there's no need to add *scratch question* and fix it later. Just write it once (even if it will take an hour) to make sure that it won't be closed afer 10 seconds and people will be able to help you ;)

Comment: Since you are asking.. its because I lack the experience to know it will hide some of my code completelly and reformat the other losing all format on editor.

Comment: During writing the question/answer you have live preview below the form, you can see each change right after writing, sometimes needs scrolling down.